# I want to create an MenuBased ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class MenuList
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
        int y;
        do
        {

            //String n="";
            //int i=0;
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("       MENU");
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("Press 1 to Add an Array with to List : ");
            System.out.println("Press 2 to Remove an Array from the List : ");
            System.out.println("Press 3 to Add Array at an Index in the List : ");
            System.out.println("Press 4 to Replace an Array in the List: ");
            System.out.println("Press 5 to Show the Output : ");
            System.out.println("Press 6 to exit");
            y=sc.nextInt();
            //int [] arr= new int[5];


            switch(y)
            {
                case 1: 
                    System.out.println("Enter the Element to be added " );
                    items.add(sc.next());
                    break;                  
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter the Element's postion which you want to Remove " );
                    items.remove(sc.nextInt());
                    break;
```

- at case 3 and 4 i am getting the same error as before. input mismatch

  ```
              case 3: 
                  System.out.println("Enter the Elements postion and Element to be added : ");
                  items.add(sc.nextInt(),sc.next());
                  break;
  ```
- index starts from 0 and increments. i input 4 values and then tried to
  change the value at 2nd index it showed me the Input mismatch error

  ```
              case 4:
                  System.out.println("Enter the Elements postion and Element to be replaced :");
                  items.set(sc.nextInt(),sc.next());
                  break;

              case 5:
                  System.out.println("Values you stored are as follows : " +items );
                  break;
              case 6 : 
                  break;
              default: 
                  System.out.println("You Have Entered Invalid Choice ");             
          }
      }
      while(y != 6);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: What is the purpose of variable `n` in your code? Get rid of it, and your `InputMismatchException` will go away. --- Also, you'd want to move both `new Scanner` and `new ArrayList` *outside* the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Now i am getting the same error in case 3 and 4. do i need to add the index for case 3 and 4. if yes dn where should i add it?

Comment: i wanted to assign a variable to the inputs that program will take. So i used  'n' and initialised it.. is it possible? or the logic/approach behind it is wrong?

Comment: You can use `n` for something, but you needed to remove it fro the `next()` call. --- You code works fine for options 3 and 4, except that it doesn't provide *prompts*, so you're probably entering the values wrong.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by my points below. I had to read the code to understand what to enter when for 3 and 4. Was this code copied from somewhere?

Comment: No. i wrote it myself. i have a habit of writing n checking if things are working fine so once i got stuck at case 1 i couldnt move forward so didnt write the instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code working, and also a few comments:

Basically, you need to move

```
List<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
```

outside the `do`loop. Instead of modifying it, you're recreating it in each iteration. And use `sc.next()` instead of `sc.next(n)` to read strings.

- You need a bunch of error checking here, things blowup if any entry errors are made, and that's very easy to do (make an error).
- Your display messages need improvement, instruct the user what needs to be entered in what order

Comment: As commented above, Scanner declaration should be moved out as well, but the code still functions with it inside the loop.

Comment: I stopped at case one so didnt output the instructions.. was stuck at case one for past 3 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with adding is obvious, don't add 'n' in:
*items.add(sc.next(n))*
You didn't use it in next lines which is correct

Comment: I used it in the first line and got error so didnt procede futher. i wanted to assign a variable to the inputs that program will take. if i use an Array instead of a String like 'n' will it work then?

Comment: ok, what kind of input you mmake, because it works. In 3th case you can't add index of position bigger then the current size od list

Comment: Also the 4th case is working when i put 4 elements and replace od the 2nd position